# uniq() returns a duplicate record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember 2.6 and the uniq() return a duplicate records even if I used the `uniq()`

Even if I used the uniq it does still return the duplicate records, my question is my approach below is to return the uniq but it still return a duplicate record

```
foos: computed.alias('model.foos'),
bars: computed.mapBy('foos', 'bar.content'),
uniqBars: computed.uniq('bars'),
```

Answer (score 4):

If the `bars` are objects, two of them must be the *same* object to be seen as a duplicate by uniq. You may want to deduplicate by the `id` of `bar.content`. lodash has a _.uniqBy function that may help you do this, which you could wrap in your own computed macro if you'd like.

Comment: Might need an example of what is the same instance vs different objects with the same shape.